# View with OPENQUERY won't build in SSDT project

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server, ssdt, visual-studio

I have an existing database that I'm trying to set up as a database project.  I'm not able to get the following statement to build:

```
CREATE view [dbo].[VW_SOMEVIEW] as 
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([SERVER2],'
SELECT   SESSION_NAME,
         SESSION_ROWS,
         ACTUAL_START
FROM  [DATABASE2].[dbo].[TABLE2] (NOLOCK)
WHERE  SUBJECT_AREA = ''XYZ''
order by ACTUAL_START '
)
```

I'm getting the error:

> SQL71501: View [dbo].[VW_SOMEVIEW] has an unresolved reference to object [SERVER2].

When I use the variable name for the server instead of the actual server name, I get:

> SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near $(LinkedServer).

Both the server containing the view and the server being referenced are on SQL Server 2016, and I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

I've added the *.dacpac* file from SERVER2 in References, and I've tried using variables for the server and database name, but nothing works. What am I missing here?

Comment: I have both master and the .dacpac for the referenced database listed in the database project references. I am referencing the master .dacpac that was supplied in Visual Studio.  I added this to the project by right-clicking on References -> Add Database References ->  System Database -> master.   Do I need to add a reference for the master database of the server being referenced?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.VW_SOMEVIEW AS
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY (
    [$(LinkedServer)] /*we need the [] brachets to make this parse ok in VS*/
    ,'SELECT SESSION_NAME,SESSION_ROWS,ACTUAL_START
    FROM DATABASE2.dbo.TABLE2 (NOLOCK)
    WHERE SUBJECT_AREA = ''XYZ''
    ORDER BY ACTUAL_START'
    )
```